# fit nonlinear regression model to data

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear

I was wondering how can I best fit nonlinear regression model to this data, using an R package.

How can I check if model is good fitted since $R^2$ value is not returned in most functions for nonlinear models?

[image: data]
<sub>(source: [tarchomin.pl](http://ramza.tarchomin.pl/rozklad.jpeg))</sub>

Comment: What makes you think this data fits a nonlinear function and what function do you think that is? To me it looks pretty much like a horizontal line with a couple of outliers are 0.

Comment: @John: Might as well partially fit an *under-damped harmonic oscillation* (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html) or similar function.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, one possible *parametric solution* that the data might fit could be an *under-damped harmonic oscillation* or similar function: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html. In terms of *non-parametric solutions*, I agree with @joaoFaria's answer, but I'd like to extend it a little. You could use `nls` or `optim` `R` functions from the standard `stats` package: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Nonlinear-least-squares-and-maximum-likelihood-models.

In addition to the suggested use of `AIC` and `BIC` statistics as *analytic fit criteria*, you also may be interested in *regression fit visualization*, using, for example, `R` package `visreg` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg), which supports both linear and some *nonlinear models*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not terribly familiar with R but I believe the standard way to perform nonlinear regression is using the `nls` function. 
Since you do not say what specific model you are trying to fit to the data, I cannot help you any further. But maybe [this](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Nonlinear-Regression.pdf) small tutorial will help.

Regarding the adequacy of the model, R-squared is indeed [not a good statistic](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression). Maybe you can try to compare two or more models using the AIC or BIC values.